# c regex code not working?

Tags: c, regex, url

I have this code below which checks whether the user has entered a syntactically correct url. Regex code was got from [Regular expressions in C: examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085083/regular-expressions-in-c-examples)

```
printf("Enter the website URL:\n");
fgets(str, 100, stdin);
if (!strcmp(str, "\n")) {
    printf("Empty URL ");
    exit(2);
}

regex_t regex;
int reti;
char msgbuf[100];

/* Compile regular expression */
reti = regcomp(&regex, "[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\\S*)?$", 0);
if (reti) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n");
    exit(3);
}

/* Execute regular expression */
reti = regexec(&regex, str, 0, NULL, 0);
if (!reti) {
    puts("Match");
} else if (reti == REG_NOMATCH) {      //This else if always executes.
    puts("No match");
    exit(4);
} else {
    regerror(reti, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof (msgbuf));
    fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
    exit(5);
}

/* Free compiled regular expression if you want to use the regex_t again */
regfree(&regex);
```

However the regex always fails, even if the url entered is correct. I know the regex is correct but for some reason it fails on the 'Execute regular expression' part. Even if the user enters a syntactically correct URL the else if always executes.

What could be the reason for the else if always executing?

Comment: What is the output of your program?  In particular, what's in `msgbuf`  after the `regerror()` call?

Comment: There is no error it always executes the else if (reti == REG_NOMATCH)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your pattern is *not* valid!

Note that POSIX defines two flavors of Regex: Basic (BRE) and extended (ERE) (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions)).  Since you want to use the "extended" flavor, pass the `REG_EXTENDED` flag to `regcomp()`.

Here are (some of?) the problems with your pattern:

`[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\\S*)`

- Within brackets (`[]`), you don't need to escape special characters.  In fact, you cannot escape them and `[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]` will match backslashes, but not the hyphen, since `\-\` is interpreted as the range from `\` to `\`.  If you want to match the hyphen, place it first or last in the character list: `[a-zA-Z0-9.-]`
- The Perl-style character class `\S` is not supported by POSIX. Use `[^[:space:]]` instead.
- Quantifiers `{}` need to be written as `\{\}` with BRE
- The `+` and `?` quantifiers are only supported by ERE

To summarize, replace the call to `regcomp()` with this one:

```
reti = regcomp(&regex, "[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/[^[:space:]]*)?$", REG_EXTENDED);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried replacing my regcomp with yours but i am still getting the same result.

Comment: Maybe it's because your input ends with `\n` and your regex pattern does not allow trailing whitespace?

Comment: In short, using libpcre instead of regcomp is recommended to the OP :)