# Regex for this string

Tags: c, regex

The buffer string `char *bufferString` points to the first element of the following string:

> BER Berman, Jane 06/29/91 Photography;Dance;Music\n

I'd like to parse each item of the topics  last list of topics only and store them

What I've tried:

```
#define REGEX_TOPIC "^[a-zA-Z].*^[0-9/0-90-9/0-90-9+]"
char *topic;
topic = strstr(bufferString, REGEX_TOPIC);
```

Could you help me here?

Comment: I'd start by using a `regex` evaluator rather than `strstr` to evaluate the expression against the the input data.

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z].*^[0-9/0-90-9/0-90-9+]` Doesn't look well-formed. Which part(s) of `^[a-zA-Z].*^[0-9/0-90-9/0-90-9+]` are you trying to match?

Answer (score 6):

The [**`strstr()`**](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strstr/) function locates the first occurrence of the null-terminated
     string `s2` in the null-terminated string `s1`. It does not handle regular expressions.

For using regular expressions in C, see the answers to [Regular expressions in C: examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1085083/78845).