# Why does regex needs to be explicitly compiled when using PCRE library?

Tags: c, pcre

I referred to [Regular expressions in C: examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085083/regular-expressions-in-c-examples)

It seems that the regex has to be "compiled" before using. Why does this needs to be explicitly done? Why can't 'pcre_exec' do the job itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a design decision.

It could, but if it did the compilation **and** the execution in one step, then it would be quite inefficient to use the same regex multiple times. The compilation of a regex is a computationally expensive operation (just like compiling some source code written in a programming language is expensive), so if you want to use the regex more than once, then doing

```
expensive_compilation(regex_object, "/the/regular\.expression$");

for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    regex_match(regex_object, next_line_to_be_processed);
```

will be **significantly faster** than if you moved the (redundant) compilation inside the loop.

Comment: +1 - Yup, and compiled regular expressions aren't unique to C; you can (or must, or implicitly) do the same in, AFAIK, Java, C#, Python, even Javascript, although many of these allow you to (inefficiently, in cases as described by @H2CO3) run a match without compiling, too.

Comment: @acheong87 Thanks! Yes, although from a control freak point of view (i. e. "in first place, I completely disregard efficiency and focus on ease of use instead"), I don't find it too good that e. g. the POSIX `<regex.h>` API doesn't provide a convenience one-step interface. It's really useful if you know you will use the regex only once. -- Also, we can notice this compilation-and-execution pattern in SQL engines too (`sqlite3_prepare()`, for example, serves for the same purpose.)

Comment: Thanks. Coming from Perl I found it surprising that a regex compilation is expensive.

Comment: @user13107 You're welcome. In "nice and productive" scripting languages, such as Perl, speed is generally not the greatest concern :) (Not that it should be unless benchmarked - premature optimization is evil.) -- If you create a tight loop with a regex match inside and another one with a simple string comparison, I dare you the first one will run slower.