# How to test that a string follows a given pattern in C?

Tags: c, regex

I would like to check whether a string follows a certain pattern. I tried `sscanf`, but I do not get the desired result.

The pattern is simple: it consists of:

- the string "while" followed by
- one or more spaces, followed by
- a string made of alpha characters or the underscore character, followed by
- zero or more spaces, followed by
- a colon ('`:`'), followed by
- the newline character ('`\n`')

Pattern examples:

- `while condition_a:`
- `while test_b :`

I tried the following, but it would not check for the column:

```
sscanf(string, "while %[a-z,_]s %[:]c", test, column);
```

Would you have any suggestion?

Comment: I think you need a C regex library. Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1085083/10077

Comment: @FredLarson No need for regexes here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems pretty straightforward to implement. You don't need either the unintuitive and quirky `scanf()`, nor non-portable (and, frankly, horrible) regular expressions:

```
int isValid(const char *s)
{
    // the string "while" followed by
    if (memcmp(s, "while", 5))
        return 0;

    s += 5;

    // one or more spaces, followed by
    if (!isspace(*s))
        return 0;

    while (isspace(*++s))
        ;

    // a string made of alpha characters or the underscore character,
    // (I assumed zero or more)
    while (isalpha(*s) || *s == '_')
        s++;

    // followed by zero or more spaces
    while (isspace(*s))
        s++;

    // followed by a column (':'),
    if (*s++ != ':')
        return 0;

    // followed by the newline character ('\n')
    if (*s++ != '\n')
        return 0;

    // here should be the end
    return !*s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your method.

Answer (score 1):

This test for your pattern seems to work:

```
   int n = 0;
   Bool ok = sscanf(string, "while%*[ ]%*[A-Za-z_] :%*1[\n]%n", &n) == 0 && 
      n && !string[n];
```

It is nice and short, but there are (at least) two flaws:

- It is ugly
- It allows arbitrary whitespace before the colon, not just spaces (e.g. tabs, newlines)

The only way to handle *zero* or more *spaces* in `sscanf` is to use it twice, once for *one or more*, and then again for *zero*. For example, this code:

```
   char tail[4] = "";
   Bool ok = (sscanf(string, "while%*[ ]%*[A-Za-z_]%*[ ]%3c", tail) == 1 || 
              sscanf(string, "while%*[ ]%*[A-Za-z_]%3c",      tail) == 1) && 
              !strcmp(tail, ":\n");
```

Comment: You should point out that the 'scan set' (`%[]`) is a conversion specification in its own right; you don't need to specify a `s` or a `c` after it.  Your code handles that.  You also insist on two spaces after `while` because `sizeof("while")` is 6 (the null at the end is counted).

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression seems like a reasonable tool here:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    const char *expression = "^while +([a-zA-Z_]+) *:\n$";
    const char *input = NULL;
    regex_t regex;
    int rc;

    size_t nmatch = 2;
    regmatch_t pmatch[2];

    rc = regcomp(&regex, expression, REG_EXTENDED);
    assert(rc == 0);

    input = "while condition_a:\n";
    rc = regexec(&regex, input, nmatch, pmatch, 0);
    if(rc == 0) {
        printf("Match: %.*s\n", (int)(pmatch[1].rm_eo - pmatch[1].rm_so), input + pmatch[1].rm_so);
    } else if (rc == REG_NOMATCH) {
        printf("No match\n");
    } else {
        char msgbuf[64];
        regerror(rc, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
        printf("Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
    }

    input = "while test_b :\n";
    rc = regexec(&regex, input, nmatch, pmatch, 0);
    if(rc == 0) {
        printf("Match: %.*s\n", (int)(pmatch[1].rm_eo - pmatch[1].rm_so), input + pmatch[1].rm_so);
    } else if (rc == REG_NOMATCH) {
        printf("No match\n");
    } else {
        char msgbuf[64];
        regerror(rc, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
        printf("Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
    }

    regfree(&regex);
}
```

This will output:

```
Match: condition_a
Match: test_b
```