# Parsing command line statements as a list of tokens

Tags: c, string, parsing, strtok

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> /* needed for strtok */
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        char text[10000];
    fgets(text, sizeof(text), stdin);
    char *t;
    int i;

    t = strtok(text, "\"\'| ");
    for (i=0; t != NULL; i++) {
        printf("token %d is \"%s\"\n", i, t);
        t = strtok(NULL, "\"\'| ");
    }
}
```

This is part of the code that im trying to make it is supposed to separate tokens

Let's say the input is `'abc'   "de f'g"  hij|  k "lm | no"`

The output should be

```
token 1: "abc"
token 2: "de f'g"
token 3: "hij"
token 4: "|"
token 5: "k"
token 6: "lm | no"
```

I get something different but close anyway I can change it to this format?

Comment: Is your input is correct ? somevariable='abc' "de f'g" hij| k "lm | no"

Comment: Yes my input is correct why what happened?

Comment: Your output _should not_ have any `|`, `'`, spaces, or embedded double-quotes.

Comment: I believe input may be like this somevariable=""abc" "de f'g" hij| k "lm | no""  .I derived this depends on your output token 1: "abc"

Comment: @JosephQuinsey Thats what im told to do and no the input is the one stated in my question

Comment: A regular expression would be a better approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085083/regular-expressions-in-c-examples

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is essentially a parser.  `strtok` isn't a very good tool for this, and you may have better luck writing your own.  `strtok` works on the presumption that whatever delimits your tokens is unimportant and so can be overwritten with `'\0'`.  But you DO care what the delimiter is.

The only problem you'll have is that `|` syntax.  The fact that you want to use it as a token delimiter *and* a token is likely to make your code more complicated (but not too much).  Here, you have the issue that `hij` is followed immediately by `|`.  If you terminate `hij` to get the token, you will have to overwrite the `|`.  You either have to store the overwritten character and restore it, or copy the string out somewhere else.

You basically have three cases:

- The bar `|` is a special delimiter that is also a token;
- Quoted delimiters `"` and `'` match everything until the next quote of the same kind;
- Otherwise, tokens are delimited by whitespace.

Comment: What if I HAVE TO use strtok, then how do I solve this

Comment: @lumpsidemash Well then it's a bit like trying to chop an onion when you only have a  spoon.  You can do it of course, except for that pesky `|` token.  Are you *absolutely certain* that it's a token as well as a delimiter?  The idea is that you just change the delimiters provided to `strtok`.  For example, if your current token starts with quotes, then you use only that character as the delimiter.  Otherwise you use whitespace and the `|` only.

Comment: One could change the delimiters on every call to `strtok`, but I can't see a pattern that would help the OP.

Comment: @JosephQuinsey As I mentioned in my question, and then made clearer in the comment, there are three cases.  The main search pattern is `" |"`.  But if the first character is a single or double quote, then the pattern is just that character.  You need to search at the next character of course.  And the `|` is a special case.  Beyond that, there's the memo issue, which is not easily dealt with when using `strtok`.  Since you have to search the string anyway, it makes `strtok` redundant.  It's easy to write something and post it, but that won't really help them if this is a homework exercise.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *getToken(char **sp){
    static const char *sep = " \t\n";
    static char vb[] = "|", vbf;
    char *p, *s;
    if(vbf){
        vbf = 0;
        return vb;
    }
    if (sp == NULL || *sp == NULL || **sp == '\0') return(NULL);
    s = *sp;
    if(*s == '"')
        p = strchr(++s, '"');
    else if(*s == '\'')
        p = strchr(++s, '\'');
    else
        p = s + strcspn(s, "| \t\n");
    if(*p != '\0'){
        if(*p == '|'){
            *vb = vbf = '|';
        }
        *p++ = '\0';
        p += strspn(p, sep);
    }
    *sp = p;
    if(!*s){
        vbf = 0;
        return vb;
    }
    return s;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char text[10000];
    fgets(text, sizeof(text), stdin);
    char *t, *p = text;
    int i;

    t = getToken(&p);
    for (i=1; t != NULL; i++) {
        printf("token %d is \"%s\"\n", i, t);
        t = getToken(&p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```