# Char validation in C

Tags: c, validation, loops

I want to add validation for a car registration number. I have declared it as a char and it must be formatted by yyDnnnn. For example, 99D2005.

I can imagine it is straight forward, is it like the charAt() method in Java?

Comment: This is not valid C at all.

Comment: Note that you probably did not declare the registration as a `char`, more likely as a `char *` or a `char []`. Else it would only have one character in.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that in C. In C you could:

- Use a regular expression parser (see the `regcomp` function); or
- Compare the individual characters and use functions like `isalpha`, `isdigit`

There are no doubt many other ways of doing it too, but what you suggest is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that straightforward.

You'll need to loop over your string verifying each position. Something like this:

```
int i;
char currC;
for(i = 0;i < strlen(carReg);i++) {
    currC = tolower(carReg[i]);
    if(i < 2 && isalpha(currC)) //continue...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regex library.  Here is a SO link to an answer involving POSIX regexes: [Regular expressions in C: examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085083/regular-expressions-in-c-examples)

Here is a small example demonstrating what I think you want to do (Linux):

```
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        regex_t regex;
        int rc;
        rc = regcomp(&regex, "^[0-9]{2}[D][0-9]{4}$", REG_EXTENDED);
        if(rc != 0) {
                printf("could not compile regex\n");
                return 1;
        }

        rc = regexec(&regex, "15D1234", 0, NULL, 0);
        if(rc == 0) {
                printf("test 1 pass: match\n");
        } else {
                printf("test 1 fail\n");
        }
        regfree(&regex);
        return 0;
}
```