# found a string with strstr() inside a txt

Tags: c, search, strstr

I want to make a code in c for searching how many times a string is found inside a txt file using strstr() function.

I have made a test code with strastr() but I have a problem.

e.g I have sentence like `" this is a text"` and when I search for `"is"` I get a result `"is found 2 times"` because it takes the "is" from "this". I don't want to take the `is` from `this` i want "is" as only word. Can i search without this "problem" with strstr() with some changes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char*ptr;
    char input[]=("this is a text");
    char key[10];
    int counter;
    scanf("%s",key);
    ptr=strstr(input,key);
    while (ptr==NULL)
    {
        printf("not found\n");
        break;
    }
    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        counter++;
        ptr=strstr(ptr+1,key);
    }
    printf("%s found %d times\n",key,counter);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't said what your problem is.

Comment: I suspect even your language has full stops at the end of its sentences.

Comment: for example i want search for word "is" counts 2 times the word "is"

Comment: @user3666993 And that's what it does. Unless you want the word "is" without any alpha character in front or behind, but you haven't specified this.

Comment: @user3666993 You can avoid that by checking that you're either at the beginning of the string, or the character preceding the match returns true for `isspace()`. Also, `counter` is uninitialized. Learn to pay attention to compiler warnings!

Comment: i want find only "is"o do not want part from words with "is" sorry again for my english

Comment: th[is] [is] a text : legit 2 times `strstr()` did its work fine , however you should make your own function that will check for that corners

Comment: If you're at the beginning of the string and see an i, check for the s then make sure there is no alpha character (letter) after it. If there is no alpha character, that's +1 "is". If you aren't at the beginning, check the character before the i and the one after the s. If this is satisfied, that's another +1 "is". If you're at the end of the string, just check before the i for no alpha then after the s for NULL or a period (if the sentence has a period stop). Do these checks for whenever you find a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want to do some form of regular expression in C. And in your example, you're looking for `"\bis\b"`, rather than the characters `"is"` (in which case, you're getting the correct results).

You can either look into using some form of regex library. These links have some info:

[Regular expressions in C: examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085083/regular-expressions-in-c-examples)

http://www.lemoda.net/c/unix-regex/

Or you can look into implementing specifically what you're looking for. Something along the lines of

```
while(ptr!=NULL)
{
    if (ptr == &input[0]) {
        if (isspace(*(ptr+strlen(key)) || *(ptr+strlen(key)=='\0') {
            counter++;
        }
    } else {
        if (isspace(*(ptr-1) && (isspace(*(ptr+strlen(key)) || *(ptr+strlen(key)=='\0')) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    ptr=strstr(ptr+1,key);
}
```

Note: I know that this code is far from being optimised, but I think it's code that works and is pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

That's the expected behavior, strstr() function doesn't match for whole words it's simply a string matcher that matches any substring found. for your requirements, you need to write a custom string matcher that searches for whole words and matches them.

one way to do it is:

```
     1- Read the file character by character, skip all non alpha characters.
     2- Start matching the word you are searching for character by character 
until either
         - You mismatch one character, now skip all alpha characters.
         - You matched the whole word, 
             - if the next character in the file is non-Alpha 
                 - Increment your counter.
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/

Comment: thanks i will try with this way but i think is more easy with isspace