# Extract string between two specific strings in C

Tags: c, string, strtok

How do you extract strings between two specified strings? 
For Example:
`<title>Extract this</title>`. Is there a simple way to get it using `strtok()` or anything simpler?

EDIT: The two specified strings are `<title>` and `</title>` and the string extracted is `Extract this`.

Comment: `strstr()` is better.

Comment: Just to echo what Mr. @iharob said, see [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr).

Comment: I think OP wanted something along the lines of `<title>[extract me]<title>` as a [regexp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085083/regular-expressions-in-c-examples).

Comment: `sscanf(string, "<title>%[^<]</title>", extracted_string);` or `sscanf(string, "%*[^>]>%[^<]<%*[^>]>" , extracted_string);` will do the job. Checking the return value is also recommended. The `</title>` in the first `sscanf` and `<%*[^>]>`in the second aren't required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Search for the first sub string using `strstr()`.
- If found, save the array index of the sub string
- From there, search for the next sub string.
- If found, everything between `[ [start of sub string 1] + [length of sub string 1] ]` and `[start of sub string 2]` is the string you are interested in.
- Extract the string using `strncpy()` or `memcpy()`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Sub string 1: `<title>`, sub string 2 `</title>`. What's the problem?

Comment: Nothing. Silly me. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how you can do it, it's not checking the input string integrity

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *extract(const char *const string, const char *const left, const char *const right)
{
    char  *head;
    char  *tail;
    size_t length;
    char  *result;

    if ((string == NULL) || (left == NULL) || (right == NULL))
        return NULL;
    length = strlen(left);
    head   = strstr(string, left);
    if (head == NULL)
        return NULL;
    head += length;
    tail  = strstr(head, right);
    if (tail == NULL)
        return tail;
    length = tail - head;
    result = malloc(1 + length);
    if (result == NULL)
        return NULL;
    result[length] = '\0';

    memcpy(result, head, length);
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    char  string[] = "<title>The Title</title>";
    char *value;

    value = extract(string, "<title>", "</title>");
    if (value != NULL)
        printf("%s\n", value);
    free(value);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have to free `value` if it was declared on the stack?

Comment: @user1717828 No you must not free it.

Comment: @user1717828 it's **not** a stack variable, please read the code carefuly. The pointer is stored on the stack, the data the poitner points to is on the heap clearly, since it was allocated with `malloc()` in `extract()`.

Comment: whoops, still learning C!  So you point `result` to memory on the heap, return the `result` pointer to `value`, and at the end run `free(value);` to free up the memory that `result` was pointed to?  Is it standard to free up space with a different pointer than initial allocation was assigned to?  Sorry for the erroneous edit.

Comment: It's a different pointer pointing to the same address returned by `malloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30302386/2173917) by Mr. **@Lundin** is nice one. However, just to add a bit more generic approach, (without depending on the `<tag>` value itself), you can also do like,

1. Locate the first instance of `<` [tag opening angle bracket] using [`strchr()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr)
2. find the first first instance of `>` [tag closing angle bracket] using [`strchr()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr).
3. save the indexes and the difference of two indexes, copy the string to a temporary array. will treat as the `tag` value.
4. Locate the last instance of `<` [tag opening angle bracket] using [`strrchr()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strrchr)
5. find the last instance of `>` [tag closing angle bracket] using [`strrchr()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strrchr).
6. Again, save the indexes and the difference of two indexes, copy the string to another temporary array. Compare with previously stored `tag` value, if equals, do a `memcpy()` / `strdup()` from `acualarray[first_last_index]` (closing starting tag) upto `acualarray[last_first_index]` (starting of closing tag.)