# regular expressions in C match and print

Tags: c, regex

I have lines from file like this:

```
{123}   {12.3.2015 moday}    {THIS IS A TEST}
```

is It possible to get every value between brackets `{}` and insert into array?

Also I wold like to know if there is some other solution for this problem...

to get like this:

```
array( 123,
      '12.3.2015 moday',
      'THIS IS A TEST'
     )
```

My try:

```
  int r;
  regex_t reg;
  regmatch_t match[2];
  char *line = "{123}   {12.3.2015 moday}    {THIS IS A TEST}";

  regcomp(&reg, "[{](.*?)*[}]", REG_ICASE | REG_EXTENDED);

  r = regexec(&reg, line, 2, match, 0);
  if (r == 0) {
    printf("Match!\n");
    printf("0: [%.*s]\n", match[0].rm_eo - match[0].rm_so, line + match[0].rm_so);
    printf("1: %.*s\n", match[1].rm_eo - match[1].rm_so, line + match[1].rm_so);
  } else {
    printf("NO match!\n");
  }
```

This will result:

```
123}   {12.3.2015 moday}    {THIS IS A TEST
```

Anyone know how to improve this?

Comment: You don't really need a regex for this... but, if you say you do, doing this in C without any external libraries is going to be quite hard.

Comment: I didn't know I am new to C, how can I do it without regex?

Comment: [`\{([^}]*)\}`](https://regex101.com/r/yR8tO7/1)

Comment: Ok that is regex but how to implement that in C?

Answer (score 2):

To help you you can use the [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bB6sE8/1) website which is really useful.

Then I suggest you to use this regex:

```
/(?<=\{).*?(?=\})/g
```

Or any of these ones:

```
/\{\K.*?(?=\})/g
/\{\K[^\}]+/g
/\{(.*?)\}/g
```

Also available here for the first one:

https://regex101.com/r/bB6sE8/1

In C you could start with this which is an example for [here](https://gist.github.com/ianmackinnon/3294587):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main ()
{
    char * source = "{123}   {12.3.2015 moday}    {THIS IS A TEST}";
    char * regexString = "{([^}]*)}";
    size_t maxGroups = 10;

    regex_t regexCompiled;
    regmatch_t groupArray[10];
    unsigned int m;
    char * cursor;

    if (regcomp(&regexCompiled, regexString, REG_EXTENDED))
    {
        printf("Could not compile regular expression.\n");
        return 1;
    };

    cursor = source;
    while (!regexec(&regexCompiled, cursor, 10, groupArray, 0))
    {
        unsigned int offset = 0;

        if (groupArray[1].rm_so == -1)
            break;  // No more groups

        offset = groupArray[1].rm_eo;
        char cursorCopy[strlen(cursor) + 1];
        strcpy(cursorCopy, cursor);
        cursorCopy[groupArray[1].rm_eo] = 0;
        printf("%s\n", cursorCopy + groupArray[1].rm_so);
        cursor += offset;
    }
    regfree(&regexCompiled);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The main problem is how to implement that in C programing language. :)

Comment: Have you looked at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085083/regular-expressions-in-c-examples) ?

Comment: @VladimirDjukic so you should update your original question with what you tried. Now that you have expressions to use and a code example to go off of. Show us what "isn't working" in that.

Comment: I updated question, could someone help me fix regex from my question?For this try get: "Could not compile regular expression."

Comment: Unfortunately the first regular expressions I showed to you are PCRE. To use them in C you will need `#include <pcre.h>`. I modified my answer to match your question