# regex in C (using regex.h) for roman numbers recognition

Tags: c, regex, roman-numerals

Using this code, i created a function that take a string and check if it correspond to a roman number(inspiring myself from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085083/regular-expressions-in-c-examples))

```
int checkregex(char *in){
regex_t regex;
char *expression="^M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$";
int reti;
char msgbuf[100];

/* Compile regular expression */
reti = regcomp(&regex, expression, 0);
if (reti) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n");
    exit(1);
}

/* Execute regular expression */
reti = regexec(&regex, in , 0, NULL, 0);
if (!reti) {
    printf("Match\n");
    return 1;
}
else if (reti == REG_NOMATCH) {
    printf("No match\n");
    return 0;
}
else {
    regerror(reti, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
    fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
    exit(1);
}
return 0;
```

}

my problem is that it always return "No match", so i wonder if my regex is not compatible with POSIX, or if i miss something else...

could someone help me out ?

Comment: Add `REG_EXTENDED` flag as you are using limiting quantifiers without escaping braces and start/end string anchors.

Comment: thanks, that was it :)

Comment: it seems that the call to `regfree()` is missing, so the posted code will have a memory leak

Comment: is `<regex.h>` standard, or else what library is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `REG_EXTENDED` flag as you are using limiting quantifiers without escaping braces and start/end string anchors.

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/xxTulr):

```
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int checkregex(char *in){
  regex_t regex;
  char *expression="^M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$";
  int reti;
  char msgbuf[100];

  /* Compile regular expression */
  reti = regcomp(&regex, expression, REG_EXTENDED);
  if (reti) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n");
    return -1;
  }

  /* Execute regular expression */
  reti = regexec(&regex, in , 0, NULL, 0);
  if (!reti) {
    printf("Match\n");
    return 1;
  }
  else if (reti == REG_NOMATCH) {
    printf("No match\n");
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    regerror(reti, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
    fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
    exit(1);
  }
  return 0;
}

int main(void) { 
    int x = checkregex("XII");
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this answer uses C++ code, but the question is about C code.

Comment: @user3629249: The original problem was with using a POSIX BRE regex with regex.h module, but I agree the code does not agree with the tag. I replaced C++ with C code sample. Best regards.

Comment: Has the code been modified or am I missing the "C++" part??

Comment: @RichardMcFriendOluwamuyiwa There were some C++ inserts in the initial version.