# Is there any function in C similar to LIKE in SQL to compare 2 strings?

Tags: c, string, search, compare

I meant, something that we can use this way:

```
char string1[] = "???, buddy*\0";
char string2[] = "Hey, buddy, hello!\0";
if (like(string1, string2) 
    puts("strings are similar!");
else
    puts("string are different!");
```

Comment: not sure strcmp will do it.  I suspect the OP would expect string1 and string2 to be 'like' seeing as how, if we treat string1 as a regular expression, then string2 would match.  That said, the OP might want to look at a regular expression library for C

Comment: @haccks Does `strcmp` accept mask symbols? Like `?` and `*`?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. OP is asking for globs, not regular expressions.

Comment: POSIX provides functions for globs (wildcards like `?` and `*`) in `fnmatch.h`. The function you need is called `fnmatch()`.

Comment: If you want something simple like "%xxx%", you could use strstr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a regular expression library.  See this question for the ANSI library information: [Regular expressions in C: examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085083/regular-expressions-in-c-examples)