# Count word in string

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a function to count occurrences of a particular word in a string. For example: Given string -

"S**to**p, time **to** go home. **To**do fix me."

Letters "to" appeared three times (twice in different words); however, the word "to" appears only once. What should I do to count only word "to" (if will appear in string more times then count every single one). Any advice? 
This is the code I was trying and playing around.

```
int word(char inputLine[]) {
    int word = 0, i = 0, j = 0;

    for (i = 0; inputLine[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            if (inputLine[i] == 't' || inputLine[i] == 'o' || inputLine[i] != ' ') {
                word++;
            }
    }
    return word;
}
```

Comment: Use **strtok** function first to split by white spaces to get words, then compare tokens to the search word.

Comment: Note that `To` in `Todo` is not the same as `to` in `Stop` or `to`.  Are you after case-insensitive matching of words?  Should the string "To be or not to be" count 1 or 2 words 'to'?

Comment: Also, are you sure you want to hard-code the word 'to' into the code?  Wouldn't it be more useful to have an interface `int count_word(const char *input, const char *word)` which will look for a given word (character sequence) in the input.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "To be or not to be" should be 2 words. I was trying to do simple example and than expands to function that counts words typed only from a home row on keyboard. using letters "a,s,d,f,g,h,j,k,l" ex "alaska" is typed from home row but "also" is not from home row because "o" is used

Comment: There are a lot of cornercases. I would use regex and a case-insensitive search for `\bto\b`. Though `strtok` splitting by spaces, dots, comas, whatever could work too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So I'm trying to count only words typed from home row.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: What about `tolower()`? Yes, it's locale-dependent, but for ASCII(1), the "C" locale should work just fine. ((1) or EBCDIC, or anything non-extended [e.g. not ISO-8869-* or UTF-8 or similar] that string literals use)

Comment: you can iterate through the text via the library function `strstr()` after iterating through the text to pass each character through the `tolower()` function.   That way there is no need to re-invent the wheel and every instance of `to`, `To`, `tO` and `TO` will be counted

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int word(char inputLine[]) {
    int word = 0, i = 0;

    // stop before the last char
    for (i = 0; inputLine[i] != '\0' && inputLine[i+1] != '\0'; i++) {

        // is (T or t) and (O or o)
        if ((inputLine[i] == 't' || inputLine[i] == 'T') && (inputLine[i+1] == 'o' || inputLine[i+1] == 'O')) {

            // after the 'to' is not a letter
            if ((inputLine[i+2] < 'a' || inputLine[i+2] > 'z') &&
                (inputLine[i+2] < 'A' || inputLine[i+2] > 'Z')) {

                // before is not a letter (or this is the start of the string)
                if (i == 0 ||
                    ((inputLine[i-1] < 'a' || inputLine[i-1] > 'z') &&
                     (inputLine[i-1] < 'A' || inputLine[i-1] > 'Z'))) {
                        word++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return word;
}
```

Comment: Your code would be clearer if you use `isalpha()` from `<ctype.h>`.

Comment: `inputLine[i+2]` is undefined at the end of the string. Stop condition is `inputLine[i+1] != '\0'`

Comment: will stop the loop if you don't have 2 char (the current and the next one) so at +2, worst case, you'll hit the \0

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: what is the issue?  The stop condition is correct with both `inputLine[i] != '\0' && inputLine[i+1] != '\0'` to allow for empty input strings.  Within the body of the loop, `inputLine[i+2]` may or may not be a null byte, but it is part of the string (because neither `inputLine[i]` nor `inputLine[i+1]` is the end of the string).

Comment: you're right, sorry. I would create 2 variables with `tolower` at the start of the loop, which would be clearer.

Comment: @ImbarM. When I compiled your code, I got warned about unused variable `j` (can be deleted), and also about missing parentheses around the `A && B` expression after `i == 0 || A && B` in the innermost `if` condition.  The code is not wrong — `&&` does bind tighter than `||` — but the extra level of parentheses `i == 0 || (A && B)` avoids any risk of confusion.  Of course, `i == 0 || !isalpha((unsigned char)inputLine[i-1])` would also work. The cast is necessary in case your plain `char` type is signed and you have accented characters in your string — they'd be converted to negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Let's posit these rules:

> "to" can be a word only when there is no char before and after it except the space char

If you accept those rules as valid and correct you need to check 4 conditions:

```
if (str[i]=='t'&& str[i+1]=='o'&& str[i-1]!='a-z'&& str[i+2]!='a-z'){
        word++;
    }
```

Two more conditions can be included to check for the upper case letters.

Comment: Consider: "to be or not to be - what is the world coming to?".  There's no space before the first 'to', nor after the last 'to', but both should be counted.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use `strtok`. But, if you'd like to do it all by hand, the following will work. Although you only wanted the `"to"` this will work for any search string:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// word -- get number of string matches
int
word(char *input,char *str)
// input -- input buffer
// str -- string to search for within input
{
    int chr;
    int prev;
    int off;
    int stopflg;
    int wordcnt;

    off = -1;
    stopflg = 0;
    wordcnt = 0;
    prev = 0;

    for (chr = *input++;  ! stopflg;  prev = chr, chr = *input++) {
        // we've hit the end of the buffer
        stopflg = (chr == 0);

        // convert whitespace characters to EOS [similar to what strtok might
        // do]
        switch (chr) {
        case ' ':
        case '\t':
        case '\n':
        case '\r':
            chr = 0;
            break;
        }

        ++off;

        // reset on mismatch
        // NOTE: we _do_ compare EOS chars here
        if (str[off] != chr) {
            off = -1;
            continue;
        }

        // we just matched
        // if we're starting the word we must ensure we're not in the middle
        // of one
        if ((off == 0) && (prev != 0)) {
            off = -1;
            continue;
        }

        // at the end of a word -- got a match
        if (chr == 0) {
            ++wordcnt;
            off = -1;
            continue;
        }
    }

    return wordcnt;
}

void
tryout(int expcnt,char *buf)
{
    int actcnt;

    actcnt = word(buf,"to");
    printf("%d/%d -- '%s'\n",expcnt,actcnt,buf);
}

// main -- main program
int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char *cp;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        switch (cp[1]) {
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    tryout(1,"to");
    tryout(2,"to to");
    tryout(1," to ");
    tryout(1,"todo to");
    tryout(2,"todo to to");
    tryout(2,"doto to to");
    tryout(1,"doto to doto");
    tryout(0,"doto");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must use only "basic" C functions the above solutions seems ok, but in the case you want to build a more scalable application (and you want to solve the problem in a smarter way) you can use a library that manipulate regular expressions. You can check this answer: [Regular expressions in C: examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085083/regular-expressions-in-c-examples)

Regexes has the advantage that you can make the regex case unsensible (That is one of your issues).
I usually use pcre because it has the regex style of perl and java.
Here it is a very useful example that uses pcre: http://www.mitchr.me/SS/exampleCode/AUPG/pcre_example.c.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FindCountOfWordInString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "yhing ghingu jhhtring inghfg ajklingingd me";
        String find = "ing";

        int count = findCountOfWordInString(str, find);
        System.out.println(count);
    }

    private static int findCountOfWordInString(String str, String find) {

        String[] strArr = str.split(" ");
        int count = 0, k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
            if (strArr[i].contains(find)) {
                String strCheck = strArr[i];
                char[] findCharArr = find.toCharArray();
                for (int j = 0; j < strCheck.length(); j++) {
                    if (strCheck.charAt(j) == findCharArr[k]) {
                        k++;
                        if (k == 3) {
                            count++;
                            k = 0;
                        }
                    } else {
                        k = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```