# How to Wirte regular expressions in c? I am making a test case on Prime No. using concept of Regular Expression in c, Following is my source code

Tags: c, regex

How to Wirte regular expressions in c? I am making a test case on Prime No. using concept of Regular Expression in c, Following is my source code. this code should not accept any negative no.s, should not accept 0's & 1's, Should not accept decimal no.s(floating values) & neither any alphabets or characters or special symbols, I am having problem with concept of regular expression acceptance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <regex.h>


 int main() {
  int i, n, prime, flag=0;

  char ch[10],*p;

  printf("Enter the Number to check Whether its prime or not\n");

  scanf("%s",&ch);

  if(p= strstr(ch,".")){

    printf("Decimal Values are not allowed in Prime Number!\n");

    goto error;

  }else if (ch==[A-Za-z]){

    printf("Please Enter the Numeric Value\n");

  }

  n=atoi(ch);

  printf("The Integer Type Cast Value is:%d\n",n );

  if(n<=0){

  printf("%d is not a Valid number, prime number is always positive & greater than & is not in decimal 0\n",n );

goto error;

}else{

  for(i=2; i<=n/2; ++i){

         if(n%i==0){

           flag=1;

           break;

       }
     }
   }

   if (flag==0)
       printf("%d is a prime number.",n);
   else if (flag==1)

printf("%d is not a prime number.",n);

       else

       error:printf("%s is not a Valid number, prime number is always positive & greater than & is not in decimal 0\n",ch);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expressions in C: examples?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085083/regular-expressions-in-c-examples)

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply compare a string with a regex like this: `ch==[A-Za-z]`. You have to prepare (compile) the regex using `regcomp()` and then use `regexec()` to match the regex against your input string.

An old example of using POSIX regex functions can be found [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20160308115653/http://peope.net/old/regex.html).

Comment: I have difficulty in understanding direct source code, can you please provide some video link for regex.h tutorials?