# Regular Expressions are not returning correct solution

Tags: c, regex, posix

I'm writing a C program that uses a regular expressions to determine if certain words from a text that are being read from a file are valid or invalid. I've a attached the code that does my regular expression check. I used an online regex checker and based off of that it says my regex is correct. I'm not sure why else it would be wrong.
The regex should accept a string in either the format of AB1234 or ABC1234 ABCD1234.

```
//compile the regular expression
reti1 = regcomp(&regex1, "[A-Z]{2,4}\\d{4}", 0);
// does the actual regex test
status = regexec(&regex1,inputString,(size_t)0,NULL,0);

if (status==0)
    printf("Matched (0 => Yes):  %d\n\n",status);
else 
    printf(">>>NO MATCH<< \n\n");
```

Comment: How exactly is it "wrong"? Please provide example inputs that give unexpected results.

Comment: Also, can you make a [short but complete program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates the problem? You should include in the code at least one example input that gives an unexpected result, as @aschepler mentioned, but besides that it doesn't need to be much more than the code you already have with a `main()` function around it.

Comment: Looks like you're using the POSIX regex implementation(regex.h), but passing PCRE-style regexes, that are not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [POSIX regular expressions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX-Extended_Regular_Expressions), from `regex.h`. These don't support the syntax you are using, which is [PCRE](https://www.pcre.org) format, and is much more common these days. You are better off trying to use a library that will give you PCRE support. If you have to use POSIX expressions, I think this will work:

```
#include <regex.h>
#include "stdio.h"
int main(void) {
  int status;
  int reti1;
  regex_t regex1;
  char * inputString = "ABCD1234";

  //compile the regular expression
  reti1 = regcomp(&regex1, "^[[:upper:]]{2,4}[[:digit:]]{4}$", REG_EXTENDED);
  // does the actual regex test
  status = regexec(&regex1,inputString,(size_t)0,NULL,0);

  if (status==0)
      printf("Matched (0 => Yes):  %d\n\n",status);
  else 
      printf(">>>NO MATCH<< \n\n");

  regfree (&regex1);
  return 0;
}
```

(Note that my C is extremely rusty, so this code is probably horrible.)

I found some good resources on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085083/regular-expressions-in-c-examples) answer.