# Characters next to each other check in C

Tags: c

Is there function in a C library that iterates through an array and checks if two characters are next to each other?

For example : `array[30] = "example@.com"`
Is it possible to go through the array and check if '@' and '.' are next to each other?

Comment: Are you just looking for `strstr(array, "@." ) || strstr(array,".@")`?  But you'd (probably) be better off writing specific code to check it rather than making strstr scan the array twice.

Comment: Way 1:Step through the string a character at a time.  If you see a '@', record its position (either as an index or a pointer).  If you see a '.', record its position.  Also, each time you see a '@' or a '.', check to see if you already have a position of the other one, and if it's just before (1 less than) the position you're at.

Comment: Way 2: Use `strchr` to find the position of the first '@'.  Use it again to find the position of the first '.'.  See if the two positions differ by 1.  (This will give the wrong answer, though, for a string like `"ab@cd.ef@.gh"`.)

Comment: @SteveSummit already used strchr in another part of my code, needed another function for checking two characters next to each other!

Comment: I would suggest using a regular expression. They aren't built into C, but this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085083/regular-expressions-in-c-examples suggests some libraries to help out.

Comment: @TomJohnson Thank you for your suggestion, unfortunately I am unfamiliar with regex, and it isn't something I can use in my code.                                                        But thank you again!

Comment: " if two characters are next to each other?'  Can either one of the 2  characters be `'\0'`?

Comment: @chux I am not sure its possible since \0 only occurs at the end of a char string.      I could be mistaken, I am still new to coding in general.

Comment: @Math_Seeker Yes a _string_ has one and only  one _null character_ at its end.  Yet you still may want to do `pair_check("example@.com", 'x', '\0')`, in which case the `strstr()` idea will not work.  It is your call.

Comment: @chux I will try that.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`strstr`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr):

```
if (strstr(array, "@.") || strstr(array, ".@"))
    /* the characters are touching */
```

Comment: this is very nave, it depends on the array having a NUL terminator

Comment: A string is supposed to have a null terminator. Otherwise it's just an array of char

Answer (score 1):

> Is there function in a C library that iterates through an array and checks if two characters are next to each other?

No.

As OP asked about an *array* and not a *string*, a `strstr()` approach will not work.

Use the below, works even if either/both `c2, c2` are `'\0'`.

```
bool two_char_check(const char *s, size_t n, char c1, char c2) {
  const char *original = s;
  while (n > 0) {
    char *s1 = memchr(s, c1, n);
    if (s1 == NULL) {
      return false;
    }
    if (s1 != original && s1[-1] == c2) {
      return true;
    }
    size_t offset2 = (size_t) (s1 - s) + 1;
    if (offset2 < n && s1[1] == c2) {
      return true;
    }
    s += offset2;
    n -= offset2;
  }
  return false;
}

int main(void) {
  char array[30] = "example@.com";
  // expect true
  printf("%d\n", two_char_check(array, sizeof array, '@', '.'));
  printf("%d\n", two_char_check(array, sizeof array, 'm', '\0'));
  printf("%d\n", two_char_check(array, sizeof array, '\0', 'm'));
  printf("%d\n", two_char_check(array, sizeof array, '\0', '\0'));

  // expect false
  printf("%d\n", two_char_check(array, sizeof array, 'x', '\0'));
  printf("%d\n", two_char_check(array, sizeof array, '@', 'E'));
  printf("%d\n", two_char_check(array, sizeof array, 'M', '\0'));
}
```