# Unable to match \r and \n using regex in C programming

Tags: c, regex, escaping, rawstring

I have the following character pointer

```
char message[100] = "START_MESSAGE hello world \r\n\r\n";
```

I am trying to use `regex.h` to parse the above message. I want to get anything between `START_MESSAGE` and `\r\n\r\n`.

So, I tried the following code (by following answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085083/regular-expressions-in-c-examples) SO post):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    regex_t regex;
    int reti;
    char msgbuf[100];

    reti = regcomp(&regex, "START_MESSAGE*\r\n\r\n", 0);
    reti = regexec(&regex, "START_MESSAGE hello world\r\n\r\n", 0, NULL, 0);

    if (!reti) {
        puts("Match");
    } else
    if (reti == REG_NOMATCH) {
        puts("No match");
    } else {
        regerror(reti, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
        fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Free memory allocated to the pattern buffer by regcomp() */
    regfree(&regex);

    return 0;
}
```

But, I get `no match`. I thought, maybe its because of the escape sequence. So, I put `\\r\\n\\r\\n` and still get no match. I looked for raw string literal (like `r` before the string in Python). But, I get

```
error: stray ‘R’ in program
```

I tried removing `\r\n\r\n` and looked for only `START_MESSAGE` pattern, I get a match. How can I get `\r\n\r\n` to be matched or get the text between `START_MESSAGE` and `\r\n\r\n`.

Comment: `"START_MESSAGE*"` is searching for `"START_MESSAG"` followed by any number of `E`, I do believe, while it looks like you expect it to search for `"START_MESSAGE"` followed by anything.  I believe you want `"START_MESSAGE.*"` as `.` is the wildcard that can match against anything.

Comment: It seems you're mixing up regular expressions and wildcards

Comment: Thanks a lot. i thought, i can mix them. i am wrong

Comment: @Jabberwocky is there a way to get the substring?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons i tried  `"START_MESSAGE(.*)\r\n\r\n"`. Clearly its wrong as i don't even get a match

Comment: You need to double-backslash the parentheses, or probably better specify `REG_EXTENDED`.