# how to check if a word contains number in c

Tags: c

When I read from file I want to check the word do not contains the number, for example, 2sum or 23b2 but is OK if the file read the mathematical operation like

```
sum = x + 5
```

I try to put inside the if statement [a-zA-Z]* put it does not work.

This part of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int charClass;
char lexeme [100]; 
void addChar(); 
void getChar();
void getNonBlank(); 
int lex();

int main() {
  if ((in_fp = fopen("/Users/Desktop/ff.txt", "r")) == NULL) 
    printf("ERROR - cannot open front.in \n"); 
  else {
    getChar(); 
    do {
      if(strcmp(lexeme, "[a-zA-Z]*") == 0){
        printf("error");
        break;
      }
      lex(); 
    } while (nextToken != EOF); 
  }
}
```

Comment: looks like you are trying to use a regular expression.  strcmp just does a straight string compare.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085083/regular-expressions-in-c-examples) for examples

Comment: `strcmp` does not work like that: the string has to be literally `"[a-zA-Z]*"` to match.

Comment: lexeme is never set BTW, so contains null characters because global, in_fp is set / file is open for nothing

Comment: if the strcmp doesn't work what should i put i am Beginners in c language

Comment: look at the function _isalpha_ iterating on your lexeme's characters, or use "isupper(c) ||  islower(c)" where _c_ is the characters of the lexeme in case additional characters are added for your locale

Comment: i try  if (isalpha(lexeme) == 0) put give me error " incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'char [100]' to parameter of type 'int' "

Comment: isalpha must be applied on an int, not on a string, this is why you need to iterate on your string. Anyway the lexeme 5 in your example is a valid lexeme, your global problem is more complicated. How do you read formula ? the couple bison / flex can help you

Comment: my program about a lexical analyzer system for simple arithmetic expressions you said isalpha must be applied in int not string how is this work?

Comment: again you have to iterate on each character of lexeme and to apply isalpha on each character and decide what to do depending on the result. What is the complexity of the expression you have to manage ? what about to look at flex / bison to help you if any complexity ?

Comment: you have any resources can explain this point

Comment: and this my code https://github.com/huichen-cs/sebesta/blob/master/parser/front.c

Comment: Anyone have answer

Answer (score 0):

Regarding:

```
if(strcmp(lexeme, "[a-zA-Z]*") == 0){
```

This is comparing the char array `[a-zA-Z]*` to the array pointed at by `lexeme`

There are two ways to approach this problem.

First, use an `regular expression`, which requires several complexities that will just confuse you (or me)

Second, iterate over the expression pointed to by: `lexeme`  as in:

```
for( size_t i=0; lexeme[i]; i++ )
{
    if( isalpha( lexeme[i] )
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

The functions in `ctype.h` work on indivdual `int` values and when referencing: `lexeme[i]` that single character gets prompted to an 'int'

Comment: it is work but the problem when see any number the program stop like x = 5 i do not know why it is stop must not stop

Comment: i do this 
             for( size_t i=0; lexeme[i]; i++ ){
    
            if((!isalpha(lexeme[0]) ) && (isdigit (lexeme[i]))  ){
        printf("erreo ");
       
       exit(0);
            } else{ }.     but the problem here when see the number is stop how i do if just the first number

Comment: the function: `isdigit()` says the digit is a number.  So that likely will not work for what your looking to accomplish